# Google Translate in python inconsistency

Tags: python, google-translation-api

I am trying to use google translate in python to convert Russian to English, but my code only works some of the time and for some reason after leave and come back to it a few hours later. I believe I have narrowed it down to where my inconsistency is coming from and will link it below. My code output that works some of the time should be:

```
Прогноз дорожной ситуации на базе статистических данных для оптимизации движения общественного транспорта в реальном времени. (ru) --> Traffic forecast based on statistical data to optimize public transport traffic in real time. (en)
```

The problem is most of the time if gives me:

```
Прогноз дорожной ситуации на базе статистических данных для оптимизации движения общественного транспорта в реальном времени. (en) --> Прогноз дорожной ситуации на базе статистических данных для оптимизации движения общественного транспорта в реальном времени(en).
```

What would you recommend I do to make it work 100% of the time.

Here is my code if you have any recommendations and [here is the link for how I got it](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/translate-text-in-python):

```
translation = translator.translate(part, src="ru", dest="en")print(f"{translation.origin} ({translation.src}) --> {translation.text ({translation.dest})")
```

Comment: Please edit the full error message you get into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). You need to provide a [mre] _as part of your question_ that people can copy into their environments and replicate your issue. Remember to do some [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and narrow down the source of the problem first! Also include the _full stack trace_ for your error so people can see exactly where it originates